# Table percentage of one variable controlled for other variables

Tags: r

I have a big data set containing information about the number of years children lived at home, education status of their mother and survey year. I'm trying to create a table that shows the *percentage of people living with their parents for 15 years* during *each survey year*, controlled for their *mothers education* (using casmin-index).

The table should look something like this:

|  | % 15 years in survey year 2000 | % 15 years in survey year 2005 | % 15 years in survey year 2010 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| casmin_mother1 | ... |  |  |
| casmin_mother2 |  |  |  |
| casmin_mother3 |  |  |  |

Example data would be:

```
df <- data.frame(years = c(15,14,15,15,12,15,11,4,1,15), 
             casmin_mother= c(3,3,2,1,2,1,3,2,1,2), 
             sample_year = c(2000, 2005, 2000,2005, 2000, 2005, 2000, 2005, 2000, 2005))
```

I asked this question here before in different form and got the following answer which sadly didn't work (which I only found out yesterday due to holidays, so posting on the old question would be awkward I think?):

```
df %>% 
  group_by(sample_year) %>% 
  mutate(fifteen= (sample_year == 15)/n()) %>% 
  group_by(sample_year, casmin_mother) %>% 
  summarise(fifteen_prop = sum(fifteen))
```

This would create the table in a different form which is no problem, but the percentages are off. I think it might have to do with `n()` using the complete column and not the column sorted by sample year, but I really couldn't figure it out.

I also tried various `aggregate`, `filter` and `if_any` ideas, but they all failed in (at least) one regard.

Also I have a weight variable for each row, so if that could be included that would be a nice bonus, but I think I could figure that out once I have the "base table".

I'm sorry for the (sort of) repost and hope anyone can help me with this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to `group_by` both `sample_year` and `casmin_mother`, compute your percentages and then `pivot_wider` to get the output format you want.  Also, do you want the percentage of respondants who have been living at home for *exactly* fifteen years or for fifteen years *or more*?

Comment: Thanks, i will try that out. Also, it is *exactly* fifteen, since that's the maximum.

Could you help me with a sample code how that would look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
> aggregate(df, years ~ sample_year + casmin_mother, FUN = function(x) 100 * sum (x == 15) / length(x))
  sample_year casmin_mother years
1        2000             1     0
2        2005             1   100
3        2000             2    50
4        2005             2    50
5        2000             3    50
6        2005             3     0
```

To get to the structure you showed, you can use the reshape2 package.

```
> ds <- aggregate(df, years ~ sample_year + casmin_mother, FUN = function(x) 100  * sum(x == 15) / length(x))

> dcast(ds, casmin_mother ~ sample_year, value.var = 'years')
  casmin_mother 2000 2005
1             1    0  100
2             2   50   50
3             3   50    0
```

Comment: Thank you **SO** much. I tried doing exactly this for so long with aggregate. I really have to get better at using functions.

Comment: One more question: I have a case weight, so that each person in the sample with x==15 represents multiple cases. Do you know where I would have to add that weight in your code? I tried it in the ```FUN``` but that didn't seem to be the correct approach.

Comment: You can work with multiple columns in `aggregate()` but I think `FUN` is applied to each separately (someone may correct me). Instead, you might try one of the following options (remember to install and load the packages first). With data.table: `dat[, .(res = sum(years * caseweight)), by = .(sample_year, casmin_mother)]` or with dplyr: `dat %>% group_by(sample_year, casmin_mother) %>% summarize(res = sum(years * caseweight))`. I've just used a nonsense function (sum of product), but you get the idea. I prefer the data.table package.

Comment: If you want to weight the proportion *after* you calculate it, you can do that row-by-row without a grouped operation.